# MapView drop annotation pin with animation IN SWIFT 2.0

Tags: swift, animation, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I need to animate an annotation addition in my code.

I've got the following code:

```
//Add an annotation
let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(mapView)
let newCoordinates = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
pinLocation = newCoordinates
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = newCoordinates
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

The issue with this, is that the pin simply appears. I need it to be animated as it drops down.

How can this be **done in swift?** (I need to emphasise this because somebody with a similar question got marked as duplicate, but the duplicate suggestion was written in objective-c)

I need **swift** for this please!

Comment: Thanks in advance! I know this should be a simple fix :)

Comment: You need to implement the delegate method `viewForAnnotation` and set the property `animatesDrop` of the `MKPinAnnotationView` instance to `true`

Comment: Code please? If it works I'll select you as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your map is out let connection fits and checkout the delegates too. if everything is perfect then your annotation method should be called. check this condition once. if not try the following link

https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial